# app freezes during populating a dropdown with a huge amount of records

Tags: javascript, performance, dijit.form

I have a dijit.form.filteringselect dropdown in my app so users can select a project name. When app starts, it queries a rest end point, gets a unique list of project names, and populates the dropdown.

The problem is that there are about 200,000 unique project names (about 700 KB), and the app freezes during populating (about 10 seconds). After the dropdown gets populated, everything works great. But it's really unacceptable for the app to freeze for about 10 seconds. Is there a solution for this? may be a better design?

The app was built with Dojo framework/html5/css and consumes rest services.

Comment: move to two drop downs; one for first letter, the other for all the names under that letterm dynamically filling the later by the change of the former.

Comment: I can see that's gonna work, but really prefer one control. I just did some research and think querybox or searchbox would work.

Comment: fwiw, just adding that many dom elements will slow down the page. if you can keep most as vars instead of HTML, you will be a lot better off. there's a few ways to accomplish that.

Comment: thanks dandavis. can you please detail the ways of doing that? Thanks a lot.